# TypeError: todos.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am building a todo app with React, Redux and TypeScript with hooks.

I cannot figure out why it succesfully compiles but fails to run in the browser.

Error:

```
TypeError: todos.map is not a function.
```

I have checked the type of `todo` which is of type `Todo[]` (i.e. an array) and, correspondingly, it can iterate using `map`.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-meadow-53w0u?file=/src/App.tsx

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useTypedSelector } from "./index";


function AddToDo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleInput(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  //dispatch to store
  function handleAddTodo() {
    dispatch({ text: input })
    setInput("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => handleInput(e)} value={input} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

//TodoList
export interface Todo {
  text: string;
}

function TodoList() {
  const todos = useTypedSelector((state) => state)

  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {todos.map((todo: Todo) => {
        return <Todo todo={todo} />;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

//Todo
function Todo({ todo }: { todo: Todo }) {
  return <li>{todo.text}</li>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddToDo />
      <TodoList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider, TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import App, { Todo } from './App';

//actions
const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'

type Action = AddTodo

export function addTodo(text: string) {
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO,
        text
    }
}
type AddTodo = ReturnType<typeof addTodo>

const INITIAL_STATE = [] as Todo[]
//reducer
function todoReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action: Action): Todo[] {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            const todos: Todo[] = [
                ...state,
                {
                    text: action.text,
                }
            ]
            return todos
        default:

            return state
    }
}

const todoApp = combineReducers({
    todos: todoReducer
}
)

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof todoReducer>

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

//store
const store = createStore(todoApp)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: why not posting your code here ?

Comment: I think todos is not an array.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. You might have typed that Todo[] at compile time, but what's the *value at runtime?*

Comment: @Ali Code is already pasted.

Comment: Map is array function, so todos is not a array.

Comment: @jonrsharpe MRE is already there.

Comment: No it isn't. There's an off-site link to code, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: You codesandbox link is not working. It seems that your index.tsx file is not the good one (it is just a copy of app.tsx), and also, @types/redux is missing as dependency.

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret Fixed index.tsx. @types/redux is not available.

Comment: still seeing the incorrect index.tsx file

Comment: @andymccullough Can you clear your cache and try again? I can confirm index.tsx is correct and I see it compiles.

Comment: The error implies `todos` is not an array, what do you get when you `console.log(todos)`..?

Comment: Per the link I provided (all emphases in originals), *"Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**"*. This is also covered in [ask], *"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to ... then do so - but **also copy the code into the question itself**."* You still haven't provided the actual outputs - *where* is the error thrown, and what debugging have you done to see what the value actually is if not an array?

Comment: @JohnHass, if you fixed it, you made a fork to the initial sandbox, so should provide a new link. @types/redux is available, I managed to add it. Also, the way you write your comments seems aggressive. Do not forget that people here do not owe you anything. They are kindly answering you because they want to help you.

Comment: @Keith `VM1861:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: todos is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:15`

Comment: mmm, that doesn't make sense.  You would have got that error before, where did you put the `console.log`..  Did you put after the `const todos = ` bit..  Because `todos` should really exists at this point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per @JohnHass
>
> because RootState isn't the actual type of the root state, you've made
>   it Todo[] when the state is actually { todos: Todo[] }

---

Then you need to change is from this

```
const todos = useTypedSelector(state => state);
```

To :

```
const todos = useTypedSelector(state => state.todos);
```

**state was not returning array but object with todos key,**

---

**Another issue :**

Not passing event type :

```
function handleAddTodo() {
    dispatch({ text: input }); // <--- Not even passing action type
    setInput("");
}
```

Change it to :

```
function handleAddTodo() {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_TODO", text: input });
    setInput("");
}

//-------------- OR ---------------

import { useTypedSelector , addTodo } from "./index";

//dispatch to store
function handleAddTodo() {
    dispatch(addTodo(input));
    setInput("");
}
```

[image: Edit so-useselector-issue]

Comment: I see it works on codesandbox, but it does not work on my machine: `TypeScript error in /Downloads/53w0u/src/App.tsx(35,49):
Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'Todo[]'.  TS2339`. Where should I look into or what info should I provide?

Comment: Note you can `dispatch(addTodo(input));`, the action creator already existed in index.

Comment: @JohnHass because `RootState` isn't the actual type of the root state, you've made it `Todo[]` when the state is actually `{ todos: Todo[] }`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This solves my issue. Thanks. Out of curiosity, in the sandbox, why does `Todo[]` still work?

Comment: @JohnHass, there might be some limitation of online editor tools, will you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

Your `state.todos` is an Array, but you are assigning `const todos` to the entire `state`, that is an object `{ todos: Todo[], ... }`.

### Possible solutions

#### 1. Get just `todos`, requesting just that property inside the callback:

```js
const todos = useTypedSelector((state) => state.todos)
```

#### 2. Deconstruct the assignment:

```js
const { todos } = useTypedSelector((state) => state)
```

Comment: Just turning it into an array or iterating over it anyway seems like an exceedingly naive solution; might it not be better to figure out *why* it's an object not an array as the OP expected, and fix that? What object *is* it? Based on the other answer, looking at the value would have made it very clear what the problem was.

Comment: I misunderstood his/her question as trying to use an iterable object with map. I will edit my answer, thanks for your feedback.